# Want to create a view which can dump mysql database as a sql file

Tags: python, database, django, mysql

I seem to be having a problem. I want to write some code that can dump a mysql database, when an administrator user clicks on a button. I have tried writing some code in my views.py below.

**Views.py**

```
    @login_required
    def dbbackup(request):
        if not (request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_staff):
            raise http.Http404
        os.chdir('/usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms')  # This is important as apache by default goes to the user's home directory.
        os.popen3("mysqldump --add-drop-table -u " + settings.DATABASE_USER + " -p" + settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD + " " + settings.DATABASE_NAME + " >  backup.sql")
        os.popen3("gzip -c backup.sql > backup.gz")
```

Now is giving me an error `The view c2duo_mms.mmc.views.dbbackup didn't return an HttpResponse object.` If I add  return HttpResponse at the end. it will say `unbound method has_header() must be called with HttpResponse instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`.

I'm not very sure what the problem is.  but I cannot work out the solution. I sort of stuck now.

Comment: How were you adding the `HttpResponse` at the end?

Comment: @eam74: As I've said,  If I do that, I get `unbound method has_header() must be called with HttpResponse instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`.

Comment: I just add `return HttpResponse`at the end. Thats pretty much it.

Comment: @Shehzad009 `return HttpResponse('')` should work, but I think it's better to return redirect somewhere, e. g. `return HttpResponseRedirect('/')`

Comment: @DrTyrsa `return HttpResponse('')` returns a blank page. Also, using  `return HttpResponseRedirect('/')` does not work. (Does n't dump the data)

Comment: It should return blank page. You've got rid of exception, so the problem is in your `os.` lines. Do they work in python shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a valid `HttpResponse` object from the end of your method.  For example, if you wanted to return the gzip file:

```
@login_required
def dbbackup(request):
    if not (request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_staff):
        raise http.Http404
    os.chdir('/usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms')  # This is important as apache by default goes to the user's home directory.
    os.popen3("mysqldump --add-drop-table -u " + settings.DATABASE_USER + " -p" + settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD + " " + settings.DATABASE_NAME + " >  backup.sql")
    os.popen3("gzip -c backup.sql > backup.gz")
    dataf = open('/usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.gz', 'r')
    return HttpResponse(dataf.read(), mimetype='application/x-gzip')
```

This should initiate a download of the gzip file.

Comment: I seem to get this error `no such file or directory: '/usr/local/src/djcode/c2duo_mms/backup.gz`

Comment: Then you should probably figure out why that file doesn't exist after your code runs?